# Difference Between Facebook App Page and Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook page for our business, and I created a Facebook App to get a AppID in order to use it in the Facebook plugins.

I've noticed that a Facebook App has a page which looks the same as a Facebook Page.

Which one should I use for promoting to the public? The App Page or normal Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be promoting your business page. That's what people will be searching for.

Essentially, all objects within the Facebook sphere are represented by a Page. Your app gets one of it's own which, if you were so inclined, would mean you could use it to promote your application. I would also recommend locking down your application's Page so the wall doesn't get filled with spam and other dubious and possibly malicious links. You can do this in the Page settings.

Answer (score 2):

Promote the normal page(www.facebook.com/pages/yourpagename). The application page is where you would promote the application you built but it sounds like you just need a appid.

Answer (score 2):

A significant difference between an app page vs a normal page: the app page does not show the number of people who 'like' it. It shows the number of MAU instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to promote the normal Page. In the normal page you can add a tab that link your application.

Answer (score 1):

One other bit of information: If you create an ad in facebook which links to your page then it will have a like button and will show the current number of people which like your page when it is served to people.

If you have an app then it will not have the like button, but if people use your app then when an ad is served to someone that has a friend that used the app they will see a social context in the ad 'jonny B used(or played if a game) your [app/game name]' at the bottom of the ad.